# R complicated version of converting dataset to long format (id information is spread across multiple disparate rows)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have student enrollment data that is currently organized as follows:

```
df <- tibble(course_number = c("Snow", 12345, 56789, "Stark", 10111, 21314, 15161),
                    academic_level = c("John", "UG", "UG", "Arya", "GR", "GR", "GR"),
                    course_id = c("middlename", "Wall101", "Wall102", "middlename", "Assassin501", "Assassin502", "Assassin503"))
```

My actual datasets have thousands of students, as well as a variety of more columns of course information, but the main problem I'm having is converting those rows of names into a new column with repeating name values based on the number of courses each student took. I'm familiar with gather and spread, and I have been able to separate out just the name information into its own column (currently saved in a separate df), but I need to find a way to count the courses so I know how many times each name has to repeat.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the tibble created. I want to read it like you have columns for course_number, academic_level and course_id, but can't help notice the last names (Snow and Stark), first names (John and Arya) and middle names in the data. You must be part way to your solution, and I'm reading it like it's input. Showing your code might help too as a way of making . your progress and thought process more clear.

Comment: Hi both. Sorry for the lack of clarity, you are correct in assuming that I am midway through solving a problem. I had to clean up some really ugly fixed width text files with this information, and I thought providing all the code I used to do that would be more confusing than anything. Anyway, the goal was to create a new column where the names were repeated for each course so that I could then filter the names out of the inappropriate columns, thus making the data into a tidy format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be we can create a grouping variable based on the occurrence of letters in the 'course_number', create a the 'name' based on the `first` element of 'course_number' and 'academic_level' and remove the first row

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)    
df %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(course_number, '[A-Za-z]'))) %>% 
  mutate(name = str_c(first(course_number), course_id,  
                 first(academic_level), sep=" ")) %>%
   slice(-1)
```

Comment: Nice, this is very similar to what I just came up with (although I had first name, last name, middle name as separate columns, which might be easier to work with)

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful! I don't see the utility of the slice part, because there are multiple name rows to be removed, but now that there is an appropriate key column I can just filter those out.